# Add a custom type and resolver in Laravel Lighthouse

Tags: laravel-lighthouse

I am using Laravel with Lighthouse package. Now I am trying to make a listing page with all of the reviews written by customers. I am able to take paginated reviews and apply some filters for them:

- by rating
- by customer nationality
- and etc.

Current problem is that I need to show how many reviews are written by nationality and rating.

**Example:**

By rating:

- 5 stars => 1000 reviews
- 4 stars => 455 reviews
- 3 stars => 205 reviews
- 2 stars => 87 reviews
- 1 start => 19 reviews

By Nationality

- USA => 340 reviews
- France => 200 reviews
- Germany => 450 reviews

One service can be used by several customers and the review can be leaved only by the primary customer. And this is the reason why the customer is not stored in the reviews table. The customer is taken from at least three nested relations.

**Database structure:**

reviews:

- id
- service_id
- rating

services:

- id
- start_date
- end_date

customer_service:

- service_id
- customer_id
- is_primary

customers:

- id
- name
- country_id

countries:

- id
- name

I think to add a new type that is called ReviewCountByRating and ReviewCountByNationality with a custom resolvers that will run a query and get the information. Something similar to PaginatorInfo in Lighthouse.

This is my first project using GraphQl and Lighthouse and I was not able to find a example of how to implement this.

**Possible solution**

I also want all filters and scopes that are applied to take affect on the count. So I think that the best solution would be to make a query like this:

```json
reviews{
  data{
    id
    rating
  }
  countBy(attribute: "rating"){
    attribute
    count
  }
  countBy(attribute: "country.id"){
    id
    count
  }
}
```

As much as I want it to work this way I think that this looks impossible/very hard to implement if we add a @paginate directive.

**My current solution**

So I think the best will be to have a separate query that will return a graphQl type of CountById or CountByAttribute. Here is how I describe them in the schema:

```
type CountById {
    id: ID
    count: Int
}

type CountByAttribute {
    attribute: String
    count: Int
}
```

We will need both of this types because when we count the reviews by rating we group/count them by a rating field. But when we count the reviews by a country (witch is a relation in my case) will be nice to group them by the id of the relation instead of the name of the country.
So then I add a custom query in GraphQl schema that will return this information .

```
type Query {
....
reviewCountByRating: [CountByAttribute]
reviewCountByCountry: [CountById]
...
}
```

Then I run this two artisan commands to create a resolvers for added queries:

```
php artisan lighthouse:query ReviewCountByRating
php artisan lighthouse:query ReviewCountByCountry
```

And implement the counting of comments there.

This is my current solution. Will be happy to know how others implement this. If you think that this solution can be improved feel free to share it.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the query you wish to run and get your results?

Comment: @AlirezaA2F I update the question with "Possible solution" and "My current solution" section. Hope this answer you question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a field to the paginator info or next to it, I guess you need to make your own directive, sth like `@customPaginate`. An easier approach is to add a field to each row and have the count there, but for staying away from `N+1` query problems, I recommend using `@withCount`.

Comment: I am no sure how exactly I should use ```@withCount```. Can you provide me some examples?

Comment: You need to have a relation in your model that returns the instances of the related model. This will be helpful to look `@withCount` at: https://lighthouse-php.com/master/api-reference/directives.html to see an example